# What is the proper way to move a database from one drive to another in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I'm not looking to relocate the database to another server entirely, but just move the data file(s) and log file to another drive with more space. I've seen conflicting directions on how to do this, so I'm looking for the recommended proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Detach the Database:

```
use master
go 
sp_detach_db 'mydb'
```

#### Move the Database files (Xcopy through xp_cmdshell shown):

```
DECLARE @SRCData nvarchar(1000)
SET @SRCData = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydb.mdf';
DECLARE @SRCLog nvarchar(1000)
SET @SRCLog = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydb_log.ldf';
DECLARE @FILEPATH nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @LOGPATH nvarchar(1000);
SET @FILEPATH = N'xcopy /Y ' + @SRCData + N' D:\Data';
SET @LOGPATH = N'xcopy /Y ' + @SRCLog + N' E:\Log';
exec xp_cmdshell @FILEPATH;
exec xp_cmdshell @LOGPATH;
```

#### ReAttach Database:

```
sp_attach_db 'mydb', 'D:\Data\mydb.mdf', 'E:\Log\mydb_log.ldf'
```

There's more detail at this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071).

Answer (score 11):

Another way - detach database files (database->tasks->detach), move them to new drive and then attach again.
But way described by Jay S is the simpliest.

Comment: Attaching database won't be supported going forward. So please avoid using it. 
For the above case refer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx

Comment: @Varun they recommend the ALTER DATABASE procedure, but I cannot find a statement about it not being supported in the future.

Comment: @Stijn: Sorry I should have written that procedure won't be supported. 
"you can use the sp_attach_db or sp_attach_single_file_db stored procedure. However, these procedures will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. We recommend that you use CREATE DATABASE … FOR ATTACH instead."

Comment: Here is a link where it says that sp_attach_db will be removed in the future. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx

Answer (score 9):

To be absolutely safe, I would do the following:

1. Backup the database to a BAK file.
2. Take the current database offline, or delete it if you want to.
3. Restore the database and change the location of the MDF and LDF files.

Scripts sample:

```
-- Get the file list from a backup file.  
-- This will show you current logical names and paths in the BAK file
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM disk = N'C:\Backups\MyDatabaseName.bak'

-- Perform the restore of the database from the backup file.  
-- Replace 'move' names (MDFLogicalName, LDFLogicalName) with those found in 
-- the previous filelistonly command
restore database MyDatabaseName
from disk = N'C:\Backups\MyDatabaseName.bak'
with move 'MDFLogicalName' to 'D:\SQLData\MyDatabaseName.mdf',
     move 'LDFLogicalName' to 'D:\SQLLogs\MyDatabaseName_log.ldf',
replace, stats=10;
```

**Notes**

The first script will get you the current names and paths that you'll need in the second script.  The second script restores the database back to the name you want it to have, but you can change where you want to store.  In the example above, it moves the MDF and LDF files to the D: drive.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it requires much more time for the backup/restore. Restores will always take longer than copying the mdf/ldf and reattaching. It can become prohibitive with DBs of any significant size

Comment: Agreed, but whenever I start messing around with the databases, especially when there are so many developers or websites dependent on them, I like to go through backup files just in case something goes wrong and I need to get back to a good state.

Comment: What I like about this method is that at no point does the database disappear from the system.  Any logins with default database set to your database will not be affected, as they would be during a detach operation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather not enable xp_cmdshell on my SQL Server instance, so I wrote a function to do this using Powershell instead; it was especially useful when I had to move a large number of databases.

```
function Move-Database
{
    param ($database, $newPath)

    $paths = Invoke-SqlCmd "SELECT master_files.physical_name as Path
        FROM sys.databases
        JOIN sys.master_files ON master_files.database_id = databases.database_id
        WHERE databases.name = '$database';";

    $paths = $paths | % { $_.Path };

    if (!$paths)
    {
        throw "Unknown database '$database'";
    }

    Write-Host "Setting $database to single-user mode...";
    Invoke-SqlCmd "ALTER DATABASE [$database] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;";

    Write-Host "Detaching $database";
    Invoke-SqlCmd "EXEC sp_detach_db '$database';";

    if (!(test-path $newPath))
    {
        [void](mkdir $newPath);
    }

    $clauses = @();

    foreach ($oldFile in $paths)
    {
        $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($oldFile);
        $newFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($newPath, $filename);

        $clauses += "(FILENAME = `"$newFile`")";

        Write-Host "Moving $oldFile to $newFile";
        mv $oldFile $newFile;
    }

    $clauses = $clauses -join ", ";

    Write-Host "Re-attaching $database";
    Invoke-SqlCmd "CREATE DATABASE [$database] ON $clauses FOR ATTACH;";
    Write-Host "All done!";
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
Move-Database -database "MyDatabase" -newPath "D:\SqlData";
```

I also think this method is a bit more robust than the others - what if your database is split into many files or you have a strange naming convention for logs for example?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move multiple databases within same server, so I expanded the accepted solution a bit, to avoid copying and pasting or retyping commands. This allows moving data files in one script run, only changing the database name. Note this assumes that advanced commands are enabled; if not, use `sp_configure`. The data and log files are assumed to be in the same directory.

```
use master

DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(50)
SET @DBName = 'YOUR_DB_NAME' 

DECLARE @RC int

EXEC @RC = sp_detach_db @DBName

DECLARE @NewPath nvarchar(1000)
SET @NewPath = 'E:\Data\Microsoft SQL Server\Data\';

DECLARE @OldPath nvarchar(1000)
SET @OldPath = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\';

DECLARE @DBFileName nvarchar(100)
SET @DBFileName = @DBName + '.mdf';

DECLARE @LogFileName nvarchar(100)
SET @LogFileName = @DBName + '_log.ldf';

DECLARE @SRCData nvarchar(1000)
SET @SRCData = @OldPath + @DBFileName;

DECLARE @SRCLog nvarchar(1000)
SET @SRCLog = @OldPath + @LogFileName;

DECLARE @DESTData nvarchar(1000)
SET @DESTData = @NewPath + @DBFileName;

DECLARE @DESTLog nvarchar(1000)
SET @DESTLog = @NewPath + @LogFileName;

DECLARE @FILEPATH nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @LOGPATH nvarchar(1000);
SET @FILEPATH = N'xcopy /Y "' + @SRCData + N'" "' + @NewPath + '"';
SET @LOGPATH = N'xcopy /Y "' + @SRCLog + N'" "' + @NewPath + '"';

exec xp_cmdshell @FILEPATH;
exec xp_cmdshell @LOGPATH;

EXEC @RC = sp_attach_db @DBName, @DESTData, @DESTLog

go
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure the user under which the SQL Server process is running has access to the folder. For SQL2014, the default user process is "NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2014".